# subclass of google maps Android MapView not responding to touch

Tags: android, google-maps, touch, google-maps-api-2

I am making a custom sub class of google maps api v2's MapView class on Android. I have it partly working but I cannot get it to respond to touches properly. I have tried OnTouch, onTouchEvent, and dispatchTouchEvent.

After some debugging I have found that only dispatchTouchEvent is intercepting any touches, and it seems only to be receiving single touch events nothing else.

Is there something else I have to do to get my custom MapView to respond to touch properly?

Thanks.

Update:
I have been able to get it to respond to double clicking, it seems that it is not detecting any sort of sliding and other related events.